# MINIMUM bounding rect width for NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, macos, nsattributedstring, textkit

I have an NSAttributedString which I draw into a rectangle (no text views here.) I allow the user to `resize` that rectangle thus forcing the text to wrap onto multiple lines. All is good and I'm using NSTextContainer etc to figure out the text bounding height for a given width.

The challenge I have is knowing what the MINIMUM width can be - so that I don't allow the user to resize the rectangle to be narrower than the widest `character/glyph` in the string.

I have a working solution which involves getting the bounding `rect` for each glyph `(boundingRectForGlyphRange`) and keeping track of the largest - but this is a real performance killer on larger strings.

Anyone know of a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you choose your font and display language, you could compile a lookup of all possible glyph widths. Order it descending with the largest glyphs first, then use `rangeOfString: != NSNotFound`; breaking after you find one (this is your maximum glyph width).

Hard to say what the performance difference is like, but it is probably faster than fetching the width of all your glyphs every time since it's just a string comparison instead of a font measurement.

Comment: Hi Ian. Thanks for the ideas. Problem is the string can have all sorts of fonts/sizes in it - including image attributes. My thinking now is to enum all the fonts, pick the biggest and use its height as the minimum width (and also check for images)

Comment: Well that certainly does add an extra bit of complexity to the issue. Why not just pick an arbitrary minimum?